# ggplot2: How to move x-axis up, so it can be under arbitrarily picked bar on horizontal barplot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I made horizontal barplot. I need to move x-axis up, so it is placed not under the last bar, but under some bar, picked based on other criterion. 
I've tried some things, like gtable, but with no success. I would appreciate any help.

This is a picture that illustrats what I want to achieve:

[image]

Here is the code to produce sample horizontal barplot:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("RColorBrewer")
colours <- brewer.pal(11, "RdYlGn")[3:9]

no.names <- 4

name.percentage <- data.frame(name = paste0(LETTERS[1:no.names], letters[1:no.names], sample(LETTERS[1:no.names], size = no.names, replace = TRUE )), percentage = 0.85 + runif(no.names, 0, 0.15))

name.percentage <- rbind( 
transform(name.percentage, type = 1, fill = cut(percentage, breaks = c(-Inf,(1:6 * 3 + 81)/100, Inf), right = T, labels = colours)),
transform(name.percentage, percentage = 1 - percentage, type = 2, fill = "#EEEEEE")
)


plot <- ggplot(data = name.percentage, 
     aes( x = name, y = percentage, fill = fill)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", width = 0.75) + 
scale_fill_identity(guide = "none")  + 
labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) + 
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
coord_flip() +
theme_classic() +
theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
      axis.text.y = element_text(size = 11, colour = "black" ),
      axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11, colour = "black" ),
      axis.line = element_blank(),
      plot.margin = grid::unit(c(5,5,5,5),"mm"),
      aspect.ratio = ((no.names %% 30) / 30 ) * 1.70) 

print(plot)
```

Comment: Make it two plots (the second one not displaying the axis) and combine them with `gridExtra::grid.arange`?

Comment: Or don't display the axis at all and use annotations instead.

Comment: @Roland Annotations would be okay, but I can't seem to find methods to lower the text, add ticks (vertical lines) and prevent labels "0" and "1.00" to be from being cut ("0"from left, "1.00" from right). As of gridExtra::grid.arange I'm figuring it out - it's taking me some time, cause I'm new to plotting in R.

Comment: @Roland gridExtra::grid.arrange gives me two figures with very different sizes... don't really know how to make the sizing of top and bottom plots consistent...

Comment: @ltw can´t you use xlim for the individual plots? and the combine them via grid.arrange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create two separate plots first, removing the axis ticks and labels in one of them entirely:

```
plot1 <- ggplot(data = subset(name.percentage, name=="AaC" | name=="BbA"), 
               aes( x = name, y = percentage, fill = fill)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", width = 0.75) + 
  scale_fill_identity(guide = "none")  + 
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 11, colour = "black" ),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.line=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        aspect.ratio = ((no.names %% 30) / 30 ) * 1.70) 

plot2 <- ggplot(data = subset(name.percentage, name=="CcA" | name=="DdD"), 
                aes( x = name, y = percentage, fill = fill)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", width = 0.75) + 
  scale_fill_identity(guide = "none")  + 
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 11, colour = "black" ),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11, colour = "black" ),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        aspect.ratio = ((no.names %% 30) / 30 ) * 1.70)
```

Then you can use `plot_grid` from package `cowplot` to arrange the two plots, with `align="h"` aligning both plots horizontally:

```
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(plot2, plot1, align="h", ncol=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @beetroot, this is amazing! I would like to add that I found out, that when x-axis is not added in the middle of initial plot, then in order to keep nice proportions between top and bottom plots aspect .ratio's need to be deleted and there need to be one additional argument in plot_grid function set - rel_heights = c(no.bars.in.top.plot / total.no.bars, no.bars.in.bottom.plot / total.no.bars)